# 'CallbackOnCollectedDelegate' has detected in delegated in camera interact

Tags: c#, callback, delegates

I'm working application interact with scanner and i have a problem in my application:

*Managed Debugging Assistant 'CallbackOnCollectedDelegate' has detected a problem in 'Program.exe'.
Additional Information: A callback was made on a garbage collected delegate of type 'Program!Plustek_Camera.PFNCK_EVENT::Invoke'. This may cause application crashes, corruption and data loss. When passing delegates to unmanaged code, they must be kept alive by the managed application until it is guaranteed that they will never be called.*

here's my code:

using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Plustek_Camera
{
    public enum CAMERA_CONST
    {
        MAX_PATH = 260
    }

```
public enum CAMERA_EVENT
{
    CAMERA_EVENT_CAPTURE = 0,
    CAMERA_EVENT_STATUS
}

public enum CAMERA_TYPE
{
    CAMERA_TYPE_PASSPORT = 0,
    CAMERA_TYPE_IDCARD
}

public enum CAMERA_STATUS
{
    CAMERA_STATUS_START = 0,
    CAMERA_STATUS_STOP,
    CAMERA_STATUS_IDBACK_START,
    CAMERA_STATUS_IDBACK_STOP,
    CAMERA_STATUS_DEVICE_PLUG,
    CAMERA_STATUS_DEVICE_UNPLUG
}

public enum CAMERA_CAPTUREMODE
{
    CAMERA_CAPTUREMODE_GIU = 0,
    CAMERA_CAPTUREMODE_GI,
    CAMERA_CAPTUREMODE_GU,
    CAMERA_CAPTUREMODE_G
}

public enum CAMERA_DPI
{
    CAMERA_DPI_300 = 0,
    CAMERA_DPI_600
}

public enum CAMERA_FORMAT
{
    CAMERA_FORMAT_JPG = 0,
    CAMERA_FORMAT_BMP
}

public enum CAMERA_ALIGN
{
    CAMERA_ALIGN_LEFT = 0,
    CAMERA_ALIGN_RIGHT
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct CAPTURE_NAME
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = (int)CAMERA_CONST.MAX_PATH)]
    public char[] szGeneral;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = (int)CAMERA_CONST.MAX_PATH)]
    public char[] szIR;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = (int)CAMERA_CONST.MAX_PATH)]
    public char[] szUV;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct CAPTURE_PARAM
{
    public Boolean bLeft;
    public UInt16 wCaptureMode;
    public UInt16 wDpi;
    public UInt16 wFormat;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = (int)CAMERA_CONST.MAX_PATH)]
    public char[] szSaveFolder;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public class CAMERA_INFO
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 60)]
    public Char[] Name;
    public UInt16 wIndex;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public class CAMERA_LIST
{
    public UInt16 wCount;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1)]
    //      public  CAMERA_INFO[]   Caps;
    public IntPtr[] Caps;
}

public delegate Boolean PFNCK_EVENT(int iEvent, int iParam, IntPtr pUserData);

public delegate Boolean pfnRegister();
public delegate Boolean pfnUnregister();
public delegate Boolean pfnGetCameraList(ref CAMERA_LIST ppList);
public delegate Boolean pfnSetCamera(String lpName, PFNCK_EVENT pfn, IntPtr pUserData);
public delegate Boolean pfnCloseCamera();
public delegate Boolean pfnSetCaptureComplete(Boolean bFlag);
public delegate Boolean pfnSetIDBack(Boolean bFlag);
public delegate Boolean pfnSetParam(CAPTURE_PARAM Param);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class CAMERA_FUNCTION_TABLE
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
    public pfnRegister Register;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
    public pfnUnregister Unregister;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
    public pfnGetCameraList GetCameraList;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
    public pfnSetCamera SetCamera;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
    public pfnCloseCamera CloseCamera;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
    public pfnSetCaptureComplete SetCaptureComplete;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
    public pfnSetIDBack SetIDBack;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
    public pfnSetParam SetParam;
}

public delegate CAMERA_FUNCTION_TABLE CAMERA_FN_GET_FUNCTION_TABLE();

public class CAMERA_API
{
    public string CAMERA_NAME_LIBRARY = "Camera.dll";
    public string CAMERA_NAME_LIBRARY_ENTRY = "CAMERA_GetFunctionTable";
}
```

}

when i call from others class:

var startCam = m_pfnCamera.SetCamera("X100", fnCamera, IntPtr.Zero); //get error from here

fnCamera is callback function

Comment: None of the relevant code is visible.  The pattern is a common one, it is your job to ensure that a delegate object that you pass to native code always stays referenced.  Like the "fnCamera" object.  Because the GC cannot see that the native code is using it.  You need to store it in a static variable or call GCHandle.Alloc().  Twenty nine thousand google hits for the exception message otherwise ought to be enough to help you solve it.

Comment: Thanks Hans Passant, Just because of GC remove it, i did it by store in static and it works perfectly. Thanks again